# Вывод двух массивов

Tags: c++, c

```
void ArrOutput(int a[], int n)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
         if (n < 8)
         cout << a[i] << ends;
     }
}
```

Есть исходный и отсортированный массивы. Сначала у меня выводятся оба массива, но если элементов в массиве меньше 8, то вывести их повторно, как это сделать?

Comment: Так же как и несортированый, только вызов добавить после сортировки.

Comment: @nick_n_a  сначала у меня выводятся оба массива, а потом, если элементов в массиве меньше 8, то вывести их повторно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил, можно так:

```
// Функция вывод массива:
void ArrOutput(int a[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << ends;
    }
}

// Использование:
ArrOutput(arr, n);  // Вывести исходный массив

if (n < 8) {
  // Если условие выполнилось
  ArrOutput(arr, n);              // Вывести исходный массив
  ArrOutput(sortedArr, n);  // Вывести отсортированный массив
}

ArrOutput(sortedArr, n);      // Вывести отсортированный массив
```

Comment: А как это сделать отдельной функцией, чтобы выводилось в такой последовательности?
Исходный массив |  Оба массива, если условие выполнилось | Отсортированный массив

Comment: @Leco исправил ответ. По идее, можно так,  если я правильно понял